# Does Playa Del Carmen have options for celiacs?

Tags: food-and-drink, mexico, cancun

I have celiac disease and I can't eat gluten at all.

I'm considering going to Playa Del Carmen, but I'm afraid of:

- Not having restaurants
- Not having food indication for gluten.

Does anyone already traveled there (or Cancun) and can help me out? :)

Answer (score 2):

A quick google search for gluten free in playa del carmen was enough to easily sort this.  For example:

[List of 10 Best Gluten Free Restaurants in Playa Del Carmen](https://www.tripadvisor.com.au/Restaurants-g150812-zfz10992-Playa_del_Carmen_Yucatan_Peninsula.html) on Tripadvisor shows this is a common request, and you should be fine.

A [similar result exists for Cancun](https://www.tripadvisor.com.au/Restaurants-g150807-zfz10992-Cancun_Yucatan_Peninsula.html), if curious.

Comment: I've seen this, but I'd like some thoughts from personal experience :)